# For loop in python to check elements in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
keys = ['well done','come on','going to','c','D','m','l','o']
values = ['well','going','come','D']
category = []
for index, i in enumerate(keys):
    for j in values:
        if j in i:
            category.append(j)
            break
        if index == len(category):
            category.append("other")
print(category)
```

I am getting this output `['well', 'other', 'come', 'going', 'other', 'D', 'other', 'other']`

The expected output is `['well', 'come', 'going', 'other', 'D', 'other','other' 'other']`

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix your indenting? I tried to do it for you but I don't want to assume what you meant.

Comment: i did it can u pls check now

Comment: Can you describe your logic? What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Am trying to find if any element from values found in key append that element in new list called category

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: But what is the logic for `'other'`? I think you should read the linked article above and try using some print statements. If you put `print(index, i, j, len(category))` in your second `for` loop, you should get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: if i dont find the element of values in keys, append 'other' in category.. I tried that print method to bug but still i stuck here

Comment: Also, since i is a value, j cannot be "in" i.  Try "is" instead.

Comment: You have an extra "H" in your output.  Is that expected?

Comment: I know you already accepted my solution and probably forgot about this problem but while I was writing some code I remembered this issue and realized I missed an even easier solution for this problem. I edited my solution that you accepted with option 2, adding an `else` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this issue with a flag that would mark if it was found.

Keep in mind that I switched between the names of your keys and values lists for it to fit better logically and changed the 'i' and 'j' for a better meaning for the names.

You can keep your names if you want and only add the two lines regarding 'found'.

```
values = ['well done', 'come on', 'going to', 'c', 'D', 'm', 'l', 'o']
keys = ['well', 'going', 'come', 'D']
category = []
for index, value in enumerate(values):
    found = False
    for key in keys:
        if key in value:
            category.append(key)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        category.append("other")
print(category)
```

Option 2:

```
values = ['well done', 'come on', 'going to', 'c', 'D', 'm', 'l', 'o']
keys = ['well', 'going', 'come', 'D']
category = []
for index, value in enumerate(values):
    for key in keys:
        if key in value:
            category.append(key)
            break
    else:
        category.append("other")
print(category)
```

Option 2 is a more elegant way for the solution in my opinion. `else` following a `for` will trigger in case a `for` loop finishes without hitting a `break` on the way.

Prints: `['well', 'come', 'going', 'other', 'D', 'other', 'other', 'other']`

Regarding what you were doing wrong - You were adding the 'other' while going through your keys list rather than through your 'values' list.

Comment: Thanks bobby for your valuable input

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated questions, it's hard to tell if the first word in each key element will be the word in values.  This example is too broad so I've taken that into account and updated my answer.

```
category = []
keys = ['start', 'steak well done', 'come on', 'He is going', 'c', 'D', 'm', 'l', 'o']
values = ['well', 'going', 'come', 'D']

for key in keys:
    if ' ' in key:
        for value in values:
            if value in key:
                category.append(value)
        continue
    if key in values:
        category.append (key)
        continue
    else:
        category.append ('other')

category
['other', 'well', 'come', 'going', 'other', 'D', 'other', 'other', 'other']
```

Comment: your are right, but actually my output is different let me re frame the keys and values so that it will be more understandable